# How can I wire up the LEGO 2838?

Tags: motor, power-functions, 9v

I would like to know how to hook up the [LEGO 2838 9v motor](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2838c01). I understand that the Power Functions extension wire is compatible with the 9v system, but how on earth do I wire them up?

Answer (score 4):

To wire 2838 motor, you have to use one [PF extension cable](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=8886-1), one end connected to PF power source (either battery box or IR receiver), the other end has a 9V compatible plug on bottom. Unfortunately, 2838 also has its connector on bottom, so you also need a 9V cable (such as [this one](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=5041-1)) to connect them.

Comment: You could also use an extension plate (2x4 or 2x8) underneath the motor, so that you can plug the PF extension cable on it.